# Generate string from SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I have following query:

```
SELECT ChallanNo+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),ChallanDate,106) 
   FROM Challan WHERE ChallanID IN 
   (SELECT ChallanID FROM ChallanDetail WHERE PTUID=42192)
```

This query result will be :

```
151468-29 May 2012
151591-31 May 2012
```

Now I need a string like this :

```
151468-29 May 2012, 151591-31 May 2012
```

Thanks for response

Comment: I assume this is for SQL Server?

Comment: Is the output something you want to produce out of SQL or can it be done programatically?

Comment: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 2):

On versions of SQL Server < 2017, you had to use `STUFF` and a `FOR XML PATH` subquery.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ChallanNo) 
  + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(11), ChallanDate, 106)  
  FROM dbo.Challan WHERE ChallanID IN 
   (SELECT ChallanID FROM dbo.ChallanDetail WHERE PTUID = 42192)
FOR XML PATH(''), 
TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '');
```

In 2017+, you should definitely switch to `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c.ChallanNo, '-',
    CONVERT(char(11), c.ChallanDate, 106)), ', ')
  FROM dbo.Challan AS c
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ChallanDetail AS cd
    WHERE cd.ChallanID = c.ChallanID
    AND cd.PTUID = 42192
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @result varchar(max) = ''

select @result = @result + ChallanNo + '-' + 
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),ChallanDate,106) + ','
from ...

-- remove trailing ,
select left(@result, len(@result) - 1)
```

Comment: FWIW `STUFF` against a leading comma is a much more effective way to remove it than using `LEFT` against a trailing comma. Why? Well, you don't have to calculate the length, for one. :-) In this case it is negligible but on a larger data set that is a lot of extra cycles for nothing.